# How to iterate over columns and make a new column on data of existing one?

Tags: sas

I am a newbie in SAS.
I have a table:

columns:

```
column1 column2 column3
```

with values:

```
row1: val1.1  val2.1  val3.1

row2: val1.2  val2.2  val3.2

row3: val1.3  val2.3  val3.3
```

I need to iterate on columns, and for each column create a new one with extended name of existing column and processed values so that the table becomes:

columns:

```
column1 column1_proc column2 column2_proc column3 column3_proc

row1: val1.1  val1.1.v     val2.1  val2.1v      val3.1  val3.1v

row2:
val1.2  val1.2.v     val2.2  val2.2v      val3.2  val3.2v

row3:
val1.3  val1.3.v     val2.3  val2.3v      val3.3  val3.3v
```

Are there some functions in SAS language?

Comment: The way to assign a value to a variable in SAS language is the assignment statement.   If you want to create `column1_proc` then write an assignment statement that assigns it some value. Such as:  `column1_proc=column1*2 ;`  How is what you want to do different from that?  Provide some example data and what output your want from the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new variable you just need to assign it a value.  Since you didn't explain what value you want let's use a simple example of two times the original value.

```
data want;
  set have;
  column_proc1 = 2 * column1 ;
run;
```

If you want to perform the same calculations for multiple variables then you should look at the array statement. This will allow you to make a place holder name you can use to refer to a series of variables.  You can use the place holder plus an index value to refer to a specific variable.

So again using the simple two times transformation you could define two arrays. One for the original variables and one for the new variables.  Note that it works much better with SAS to keep the numeric counters in variable names at the end of the variable name. Then you can use variable lists.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array old column1 - column3 ;
  array new column_proc1 - column_proc3;
  do i=1 to dim(old);
    new(i) = 2 * old(i) ;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: yes! that's almost what i need! May be there is a simple way to generate names for new array from names from array within this proc? i have 70+ variables and now do it separately